# Angular: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected"

Tags: angular, typescript

I wonder why I get this compile error if I declare variable with `var` or `let` keywords? I mean, this goes well:

```
export class AppComponent {

    refreshClickStream$: any;

    constructor(){
    }
```

While this brings the error:

```
export class AppComponent {

    var refreshClickStream$: any;

    constructor(){
    }
```

Comment: You can not use var or let when declaring a class variable. You can use public or private. By default the variable is public in typescript.

Comment: @Faisal - Ok, but why I can declare it using var in the constructor?

Comment: because that is a local variable. You can define it using let, var or const.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Inside a class, TypeScript doesn't permit the declaration of class members with

- `var`
- `let`
- `const` [(you can use `readonly` on the property)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Further, inside of a class **ALSO** you'll be prohibited from declarating functions with

- `function`

So you want this.

```
export class AppComponent {

  a: string = "foo";
  b: string = "bar";


  foo(): void { }

  constructor(){
  }

}
```

Not,

```
export class AppComponent {

  var a: string = "foo";
  let b: string = "bar";


  function foo(): void { }

  constructor(){
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why TypeScript is not allowing this?

Comment: @StarLord my assumption is that in the case of var/let it's about variable allocation on the stack, and objects are allocated on the heap -- so it probably doesn't make sense at at all. With `const` I'm not sure though. I would think const could get hoisted outside the class and made unique and it would work just fine. Perhaps they just don't want to break the ES6 spec.

Answer (score 0):

This is the property in class and in typescript you can define a property like this:

```
@Component({selector: 'greet', template: 'Hello {{name}}!'})
class Greet {
  name: string = 'World';
  constructor(){
  }
}
```