# Angular why I am not able to declare class level variable in angular class

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tdemo';
  let num =[7,8,9]; //why getting error
}
```

why I am gettting below error while declare let num variable
"Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464245/angular-unexpected-token-a-constructor-method-accessor-or-property-was-expe)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write :

num : number[] = [7,8,9]

Answer (score 1):

`let` declares [block-scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/block) local variables.

When declaring a class scoped variable, you don't need to precede the declaration.

```
num: number[] = [7,8,9];

// You can optionally have an access-modifier
public num2: number[] = [7,8,9];
private _num3: number[] = [7,8,9];
```

See the [TypeScript documentation on Variable Declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) for more information.