# Angular : unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop

when I try to run my code when I declare a property with var or let keywords I get an error,

***this goes fine:***

```
export class productComponent {

    productId: any;

    constructor(){
    }
```

***And this show the error:***

```
export class productComponent {

    var productId: any;

    constructor(){
    }
```

doesn't typescript and javascript uses var and let to declare variables and angular is based on typescript. I know that someone will say productId is a field and not a variable , but isn't a field a variable ? what are the differences between field and variable in this case ?

Comment: They do. But here you are trying to declare a class variable so you do not need to specify `var`. You will only need it when declaring a variable inside a function or any other block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464245/angular-unexpected-token-a-constructor-method-accessor-or-property-was-expe)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a class in TypeScript for example:

```js
class Program{
    public nombre: string;
 
    getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    setNombre(nombre:string){
        this.nombre = nombre;
  }
}
```

That's the correct syntax, it's incorrect to use the var/let/const keyword to declare a property inside a class or an object.